# ManagedBean is constructed but shouldn't?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I'working on a enterprise application that uses JSF 2.0, with Netbeans 7.0 and Glassfish 3.1
I have a managed bean that is ViewScoped. this is the declaration of the class:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "myBean")
@ViewScoped
public class MyMBean implements Serializable {
```

Inside its @PostConstruct, it has the following:

```
String id = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("id");    
if (id == null) {
    try {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("home.xhtml");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
    } catch (Exception e) { }
    return;
}
```

if I go to the page that uses this managed bean, and the id is null, everything works fine, and I get redirected to home page.
The problem is that when I navigate to a different page that does NOT use this managed bean (lets say for example "otherpage.xhtml") the PostConstruct method is executed, and it shouldn't! And it gets worse: since the url of this other page doesn't have the "id" parameter, the bean tries to redirect to home page; and I get a IllegalStateException.

Any idea of why a viewscoped managed bean is constructed when navigating to a page that does not use it?

**Edit:**
If in order to navigate to "otherpage.xhtml" I use the commandlink in "home.xhtml", 6 extra beans are created.
But, if instead of using the link, I type the url in the browser; it works fine. No extra bean is created. Maybe there's something wrong in how I implemented the link. This is the code:

```
<h:form>
    <h:commandLink value="Go to other page" action="otherPage" />
</h:form>
```

And this is the navigation rule in faces-config:

```
 <navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>*</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>otherPage</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/views/otherPage.xhtml</to-view-id>
            <redirect/>
        </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

Is there anything wrong there?

Thanks!
Damian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You surely have a `#{myBean}` somewhere in the view or one of its templates/include/tag/composite files, or as a `@ManagedProperty` of the beans referenced by the view. Putting a breakpoint in the (post)constructor and investigating the stacktrace should give enough insights who/what has triggered the bean's construction.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, the `ExternalContext#redirect()` already implicitly calls `FacesContext#responseComplete()`, you don't need to call it yourself. See also the [method's javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#redirect%28java.lang.String%29).

---

**Update**: a `<h:commandLink>` submits its parent POST `<form>` to the *current* page (and thus creates all its related beans!) and then depending on the navigation outcome, it will forward/redirect to the result page. You shouldn't be using commandlinks/commandbuttons for plain page-to-page navigation. Use `<h:link>` instead.

```
<h:link value="Go to other page" outcome="views/otherPage" />
```

You can eventually also get rid of that `<navigation-case>`. If you really insist in keeping that navigation case, then use `outcome="otherPage"` instead.

#### See also:

- [When should I use h:outputLink instead of h:commandLink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317684/when-should-i-use-houtputlink-instead-of-hcommandlink)
- [Communication in JSF 2.0 - Implicit navigation](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ImplicitNavigation)

Comment: hey @BalusC take a look at the edit in the question. btw, I didn't find uses of the bean anywhere in that page

Comment: thanks @BalusC that actually solvved part of the problem; but also I had to remove all the navigation cases from the faces-config (only kept 2 or 3 that were really necesarry) because otherwise beans were constructed anyways, even using h:link. I don't know why, but after removing the rules, everything started to work as expected. One remark: I had one navigation rule from-view-id = * and then a lot of navigation-case (one for each page). maybe that was wrong..